# How to design database for a game with user progress

Tags: database, algorithm, database-design

I'm trying to build a game, which has few levels, and different missions on each level.

Game has **Levels table**

```
levels
--------------
id
description
...
```

And also **Missions table**

```
missions
--------------
id
level
description
.....
```

Each mission has parts, for example user goes through a mission step by step by parts, use can do few part of a mission and leave the game. So I need to track user progress.

**Mission Parts table**

```
mission_parts
-----------------
id
mission_id
description
.....
```

I suggest that game has to have following tables to track user progress

- User **Level** Progress
- User **Mission** Progress
- User **Mission_Parts** Progress

And checking all the time user progress, as soon as user complete all missions parts - the mission is done, and as soon as user complete all mission of particular level, level is done.

On new login it will compare **Levels, Missions and Mission Parts** table to same User tables and return user progress on each level, mission, part.

First question is, should it compare tables each time user want to see his progress or I should record user progress somehow?
And the second question is it even good way to store and track user progress in game like this?

Comment: Are parts of a mission and missions performed successively?

Comment: @MaximFedorov, Actually no, user is able to skip part of a mission, and return to it later.

Comment: What structure do progress tables have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, if a user can skip a part of a mission or a mission then you should store user progress. Structure of those tables might be following:

user_level_progress table keeps the completed level of a user

```
user_level_progress
--------
user
level
```

user_mission_progress table keeps skipped and completed missions of a user

```
user_mission_progress
--------
user
mission
status (completed, skipped)
```

user_mission_parts_progress table keeps skipped and completed parts of a mission of a user

```
user_mission_parts_progress
--------
user
mission_part
status (completed, skipped)
```

You can show user progress on basis of those tables. Of course, you must save completed levels, missions, and parts of missions in those tables when a user complete them